# How to print a “double” type value without the scientific notation or zeros in java?

Tags: java, biginteger

I built a program that uses double types, it works well, but what I want is to print the final value with all its digit. To explain for what I'm looking for, I wrote this example:

```
    /* sample number my program might generate */
    Double Big = new Double ("2937093129380193810983901274934098138098390183");

    /* Double.toString(double) method */
    String reallyBigString = Double.toString(Big);
    System.out.println(“Double.toString = " + reallyBigString);

    /* Big Integer class */
    BigInteger reallyBigInteger2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(Big).toBigInteger();
    System.out.println("BigInteger = " + reallyBigInteger2);

    /* BigDecimal class */
    BigDecimal reallyBigInteger1 = new BigDecimal(Big);
    System.out.println("BigDecimal = " + reallyBigInteger1);
```

What I would like to get:

```
the double real value = 2937093129380193810983901274934098138098390183
```

What I get:

```
Double.toString = 2.937093129380194E45
BigInteger = 2937093129380194000000000000000000000000000000
BigDecimal = 2937093129380193767890297090901187942913409024
```

the `BigInteger` result uses a sort of rounding of the value and i don’t need this.

How can i do to get the right value?

Comment: That number can't be stored in a double exactly. As soon as you put it in that double, it loses some of the information. If you want it to be exact, you need to put it directly in the `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`, not mediated by a double.

Comment: As @RealSkeptic said, you'll need to construct your `BigInteger` from the `String` instead of trying to construct it from the `Double`.  So use `new BigInteger("2937093129380193810983901274934098138098390183")` and you should get the correct result.

Comment: double can only be precise to ~15-17 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RealSkeptic and @Ken Slade said I needed to construct the `BigInteger` from a `String` and not from a `Double` and that’s it:

```
    /* the sample number converted to a String*/
    String Big = new String ("2937093129380193810983901274934098138098390183");

    /* BigInteger */
    BigInteger reallyBigInteger = new BigInteger(Big);
    System.out.println("BigInteger = " + reallyBigInteger);
```

and the result it's right:

```
BigInteger = 2937093129380193810983901274934098138098390183
```

Then I rebuilt from zero the program using the `BigInteger` and `String` types.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct way to convert BigDecimal to BigInteger

```
    BigInteger reallyBigInteger2 = new BigDecimal(Big).toBigInteger();
```

Create **new BigDecimal()** object by passing double value and then convert to BigInteger  will give the correct result.

For BigDecimal: this is a bit tricky, because they don't do the same thing. [BigDecimal.valueOf(double)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) will use the [canonical String representation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) of the double value passed in to instantiate the BigDecimal object. In other words: The value of the BigDecimal object will be what you see when you do System.out.println(d).

If you use new BigDecimal(d) however, then the BigDecimal will try to represent the double value as accurately as possible. This will usually result in a lot more digits being stored than you want. Strictly speaking, it's more correct than valueOf(), but it's a lot less intuitive.